# File groups in SQL Server and file names

Tags: sql-server-2008

What is the difference between **operating system** file name and **logical file name** for the same file while creating file group? Why do we need 2 different names?

Answer (score 0):

[Files and Filegroups Architecture - MSSQL Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179316%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> The **logical_file_name** is the name used to refer to the physical file in all Transact-SQL statements. The logical file name must comply with the rules for SQL Server identifiers and must be unique among logical file names in the database.
>
> The **os_file_name** is the name of the physical file including the directory path. It must follow the rules for the operating system file names.

Thus, the logical name is basically a convenience abstraction:

- crafted for use in SQL statements (much shorter, follows an SQL-friendly and  FS-independent naming convention)
- needs to only be unique intra-database (doesn't need DB prefix etc)